# Azure Communication Calling SDK crashes on start call

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-communication-services

I am trying to start a one on one call using Azure CommunicationCalling sdk. I am getting a crash inside one of the sdk functions as shown in screenshot for backtrace below.

Code for start call:-

```
func startCall(callee: String, successHandler: @escaping (Call?) -> Void ) {

    // start call logic
    debugPrint(callee)
    let callees:[CommunicationIdentifier] = [createCommunicationIdentifier(fromRawId: callee)]
    debugPrint(callees)
    self.callAgent?.startCall(participants: callees, options: StartCallOptions()) { (call, error) in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            successHandler(nil)
        } else {
            self.call = call
            debugPrint("call placed successfully")
            successHandler(call)
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that call agent and communication identifier arr obj passed is not nil.

Crash log:-
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

BackTrace for crash:-
[image]

I have referred to following documentation:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/ui-library/get-started-composites?tabs=kotlin&pivots=platform-ios

Comment: in which line u are facing this issue, the reason is `[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil` array try to insert the nil object.

Comment: Crash is happening inside the sdk inside ACSIdentifiers class triggered by calling SDK's 'startCall' function. Also as i already mentioned the callees param as well as call agent passed is valid object (not nil).

Comment: Can you try it by using the latest beta SDK [v2.3.0-beta.2](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/releases/tag/v2.3.0-beta.2) and check if you still have the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crash doesnt happen anymore with same sdk version. Also the beta sdk version (v2.3.0-beta.2) is working fine too.